# How to send function list as argument

Tags: java, list, tags

I have this function for taging file in S3:

```
public void setTAGToFile(String filekey, String externalS3Bucket, String tagKey, String tagValue)  {

    List<Tag> tags = new ArrayList<Tag>();
    tags.add(new Tag(tagKey, tagValue));
    ObjectTagging objectTags = new ObjectTagging(tags);
    common.tagObjectInS3(externalS3Bucket, filekey, objectTags);
}
```

I will be able here to tag only one time with key and value. How can I change my function to support getting multi tags? I was thinking to use a `for` loop and use `tags.add` in the body of the loop

```
for (Tag tag: tags)
{
   tag.add(/* ... */);
}
```

but I am not sure what to change in the input of my function?

Comment: `public void setTAGToFile(String filekey,String externalS3Bucket, List<Tag> tags)` !?

Comment: But what will be the inputs you will give the function? I am using cucumber and i want to send parameters: {(VirusScan,Succeeded),(Unzip,Succeeded)} for example. I want to give the user to send multi of key and values.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the question correct, you want to pass several key-value pairs?

On the spot I can think of three approaches:

1. Since the key is a unique value, you can pass a Map [Java HashMap](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html)
2. You can create your own class and pass it as a List
3. Don't re-invent the wheel. As luk2302 already stated, there is a class describing a tag with key and value. Why bother with a problem, if someone else already solved it? The call can be like (even if not recommended)

   setTAGToFile(
      "String",
      "String",
      "String",
      new ArrayList() {
         new Tag("Key", "Value"),
         new Tag("Key", "Value") }
   )